# Determining the type of isometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, isometry

I am working on a problem that says:

Classify and discuss the isometry $F: \mathbb{E}^3 \to \mathbb{E}^3: (p_1,p_2,p_3)\mapsto (p_2-2,p_3+1,8-p_1)$.

I really don't know where to begin on problems like this. Can someone give me some hints to get me going? I think that I can write $F$ as
$$\begin{pmatrix}p_1 \\ p_2 \\ p_3 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}p_1 \\ p_2 \\ p_3 \end{pmatrix} +\begin{pmatrix}-2 \\ 1 \\ 8 \end{pmatrix} $$

At this point I don't really know what to do. How would I go on to find out what kind of isometry it is and any additional information that can be given about the isometry?

Comment: A good place to start with this kind of problem is to ask: does the isometry have any fixed points? If so what does the set of fixes points look like (is it a point, a line, a plane)? Does the isometry leave any lines or planes invariant? If you can answer these questions, using the classification of Euclidean space isometries it should be easy to work out what you have.

Comment: When you say classify, do you mean translation, reflections, rotations and so on? And it is not clear what is to be "discussed".

Comment: Yes by classify it means translation, reflection, rotation, etc. By discuss I think it means finding the mirror plane, axis of rotation, etc.

Comment: You may ask if $ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ corresponds to a rotation, or a reflection, or a combination of both.

Comment: @ArcticChar well I know that the matrix has real eigenvalue $-1$ with eigenvector $(1,-1,1)$ and that the determinant is $-1$. How do I go further from there? I think it's the combination of a rotation and a reflection as the orientation is not preserved

Answer (score 2):

I will expand on the hints I gave in the comments, and use them to work through the solution. If you want to stop reading at any point and try and finish off the question yourself, I recommend doing this. As a warning, writing $F$ as an affine transformation in the way you did in the question is a bit of a red Herring.

**Hint 1:** Find the fixed points of $F$.

Suppose $F(a,b,c)=(b-2,c+1,8-a)=(a,b,c)$, then $$a=b-2=(c+1)-2=((8-a)+1)-2=7-a$$  which implies $a=7/2$, and consequently $c=8-a=9/2$ and $b=c+1=11/2$, so $F$ has a unique fixed point, $(7/2,11/2,9/2)$.

**Hint 2:** What types of isometries of $\mathbb{E}^3$ have a unique fixed point? Can you relate these isometries to isometries of $\mathbb{S}^2$?

For simplicity, let's conjugate $F$ by the translation $T$ which sends $(0,0,0)\mapsto (7/2,11/2,9/2)$ to get a new isometry $F'=T^{-1}\circ F\circ T$ which fixes the origin. You can check $$F'(p_1,p_2,p_3)=(p_2,p_3,-p_1).$$ Since $F'$ is an isometry which fixes the origin, it is actually a linear isometry of $\mathbb{E}^3=\mathbb{R}^3$ thought of as a vector space. Because it doesn't change distances, the set of points a distance 1 from the origin is invariant, or put another way, it induces an isometry of the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$.

There is a simple description of the isometries of the sphere, they are either 1) the identity, 2) a reflection in a great circle, 3) a rotation along a great circle, or 4) a glide reflection (rotation along a great circle followed by a reflection in that same circle.

**Hint 3:** Which type of isometry could $F'$ be, based on the description of fixed points we found?

Thought of as an isometry of the sphere, $F'$ has no fixed points, and hence must be a glide reflection, since the other types all *do* have fixed points: 1) all points of $\mathbb{S}^2$, 2) all points on the great circle, and 3) the poles of $\mathbb{S}^2$ relative to the great circle.

**Hint 4:** What is the invariant plane of $F'$?

Since $F'=S\circ R$ where $R$ is a rotation, and $S$ is a reflection we can ask what is the plane of reflection of $S$, which is also the invariant plane under the rotation $R$. Notice that $$F'(1,-1,1)=-(1,-1,1),$$
so the invariant plane is orthogonal to the vector $(1,-1,1)$.

**Hint 5:** What is the angle of rotation in this invariant plane by $R$?

Extend $(1/\sqrt{3})(1,-1,1)$ to an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, eg $$\left\{e_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,-1,1),e_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1,0),e_3=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(-1,1,2)\right\}.$$ Then, since the reflection $S$ fixes $e_2$ and $e_3$ by definition, $$R(e_2)=F'(e_2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,0,-1)=\frac{1}{2}e_2-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}e_3,\;\textrm{and}$$ $$R(e_3)=F'(e_3)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(1,2,1)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}e_2+\frac{1}{2}e_3.$$

So as a rotation in the $(e_2,e_3)$ plane, $R$ is given by the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$
and hence is a rotation by $\pi/3$.

**Hint 6:** Put it all together.

$F$ is the isometry which is a glide reflection of a sphere, centred on the point $(7/2,11/2,9/2)$, which rotates the affine plane through this point and orthogonal to $(1,-1,1)$ through an angle of $\pi/3$.

I have no doubt that there are more "direct" ways to compute this, but I hope working through the problem in a detailed geometric way gives you an intuitive understanding of what is going on.